tkinter - call grid values from function with grid_slaves
I am trying to create lists of column grid data from a function using grid_slaves. I would like the function to obtain each grid value in a column then append to a list. No lists are created but printing the first 3 lists produces:
[[<tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry>]] [[<tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry2>]] [[<tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry3>]]
[[<tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry>], [<tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry7>]] [[<tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry2>], [<tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry8>]] [[<tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry3>], [<tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry9>]]


from tkinter import*
 root = Tk()

 def make_list(num_rows): # Make array of value columns
    #Create empty lists
    value1_list=[]
    value2_list=[]
    value3_list=[]
    value4_list=[]
    value5_list=[]
    value6_list=[]

    #Obtain values in frame 1 grid
    for j in range(2,num_rows+2):
       # Obtain values in each column
       value1_column = frame1.grid_slaves(row=j, column=1)
       value2_column = frame1.grid_slaves(row=j, column=2)
       value3_column = frame1.grid_slaves(row=j, column=3)
       value4_column = frame1.grid_slaves(row=j, column=4)
       value5_column = frame1.grid_slaves(row=j, column=5)
       value6_column = frame1.grid_slaves(row=j, column=6)
       # Fill lists with frame 1 column values
       value1_list.append(value1_column)
       value2_list.append(value2_column)
       value3_list.append(value3_column)
       value4_list.append(value4_column)
       value5_list.append(value5_column)
       value6_list.append(value6_column)

       print(value1_list, value2_list, value3_list) # output above

 #Create Make List GUI
 width= root.winfo_screenwidth()               
 height= root.winfo_screenheight()  
 root.title("Value Frame")        
 root.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))# Set GUI to full screen
 frame1 = Frame(root) #Create frame for input boxes   
 frame1=LabelFrame(root, text='Value Frame 1',padx=10, pady=10)
 frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

 #Frame 1 labels
 label1 = Label(frame1, text='value 1',pady=2) 
 label1.grid(row=1, column=1)
 label2 = Label(frame1, text='value 2',pady=2) 
 label2.grid(row=1, column=2)
 label3 = Label(frame1, text='value 3',pady=2) 
 label3.grid(row=1, column=3)
 label4 = Label(frame1, text='value 4',pady=2) 
 label4.grid(row=1, column=4)
 label5 = Label(frame1, text='value 5',pady=2) 
 label5.grid(row=1, column=5)
 label6 = Label(frame1, text='value 6',pady=2) 
 label6.grid(row=1, column=6)

 num_rows = 2
 for i in range(num_rows):
   # Label row No
   label1 = Label(frame1, text=f'# {i+1}',pady=2) 
   label1.grid(row= 2+i, column=0)
  
   #Enter Data Frame 1
   value1 = Entry(frame1,width=10)
   value2 = Entry(frame1,width=10)
   value3 = Entry(frame1,width=10)
   value4 = Entry(frame1,width=10)
   value5 = Entry(frame1,width=10)
   value6 = Entry(frame1,width=10)

   #Grid Location Frame 1
   value1.grid(row=i+2, column = 1)
   value2.grid(row=i+2, column = 2)
   value3.grid(row=i+2, column = 3)
   value4.grid(row=i+2, column = 4)
   value5.grid(row=i+2, column = 5)
   value6.grid(row=i+2, column = 6)

   # Prefill grid values
   value1.insert(0, int("5")) 
   value2.insert(0, int("2")) 
   value3.insert(0, int("4")) 
   value4.insert(0, int("8")) 
   value5.insert(0, int("6")) 
   value6.insert(0, int("1")) 

 #Create submit button and call Make List function
 myButton = Button(root, text='Make List', command = lambda:make_list(num_rows))
 myButton.grid(row = 0, column = 15, sticky = N, padx = 40, pady=10)

 root.mainloop()

Would appreciate any suggestions.
Have tried a number of different grid_slave configurations but cannot create the lists

Where is the Entry7, Entry8 and Entry9?
[[]] [[]] [[]]
[[], [<tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry7>]] [[], [<tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry8>]] [[], [<tkinter.Entry object .!labelframe.!entry9>]]


You have too many errors looping for Entry widgets

The code on lines 62 to 67 should be placed within a loop. You must keep increasing the value of value(?).

The piece you're missing is that you have to call .get() on each entry in order to get the value.
Also, you can take advantage of loops a little bit better. The following function will work no matter how many rows or columns you have, and doesn't require quite as many lines of code.
I have it both print the values and return the values. Returning the values is pointless since you're calling this from a button command, but it's there in case you want to reference the values inside the lambda, or call this function outside of the lambda.
def make_list(num_rows):

    # this list will have a list for every row of data
    results = []

    for r in range(2, num_rows+2):

        # add a new row to our results
        row = []
        results.append(row)

        for c in range(1,7):

            # slaves will be a list of entry widgets.
            # we take advantage of the fact we know 
            # there is only one
            slaves = frame1.grid_slaves(row=r, column=c)
            entry = slaves[0]

            # get the value, append it to the list of values
            # for this row
            value = entry.get()
            row.append(value)

    print(results)
    return results


That worked great thanks everyone for the answer and comments! It helped my understanding of tkinter
